# TSQL - Create a GUID from a random text and then get back the original text value from that GUID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm curious, is there an efficient way to generate a `GUID` from a random string of `text` and then take that `GUID` and convert it back to the original random string of `text` without using any additional data/mapping? I looked around for ways to do it, but couldn't find anything substantial.

Take this variable as an example for the starting point. I want to know if I can generate a `GUID` from it and then destruct the `GUID` to get back the original `@Text`

```
DECLARE @Text CHAR(64) = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' ;
```

Comment: You are asking about a reversible hash.  No, GUIDs cannot be used for this purpose, unless you store the values in a table.

Comment: I've seen an example that converts a BIGINT value into GUID and back to BIGINT. Are you saying that's not possible with string without storing something for mapping purpose in a table?

Comment: . . A string can be of arbitrary length.  There are more possible strings than GUIDs.

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question due to my lack of understanding, but let's say if I can guarantee the length (e.g. 64 chars), would that help?

Comment: a GUID is 16 bytes so you can only do it for strings that can be encoded in 16 bytes due to the pigeon hole principle. 64 chars of arbitrary text is way too long

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to me now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are leaning towards `EncryptByPassPhrase()` and `DecryptByPassPhrase()`

**Example**

```
declare @encrypt varbinary(200) 
select @encrypt = EncryptByPassPhrase('MySecretKey', 'abc' )
select @encrypt 

select convert(varchar(100),DecryptByPassPhrase('MySecretKey', @encrypt ))
```

Comment: Thank you for a suggestion. I'm not trying to encrypt/decrypt this, this is not for any security purpose. I am trying to pass the random string of text from one proc to another proc as a GUID (has to be a guid - weird scenario, yes). and then get back the original text in the last proc.

Comment: @007 I'll noodle this a bit more

Comment: @007 for your actual use case of passing info from one proc to another (without creating a parameter for this for some reason) would context_info help?

Comment: @MartinSmith Never heard of this fx before, pretty interesting. A quick "bing" search indicates that its scope is at session/batch level. The first proc and the last proc will be called by different windows services at different times (though on the same DB). Maybe I didn't research enough, but seems like in this situation, it wouldn't work. Am I correct on this?

Comment: Yep, wouldn't work. I thought by passing from one proc to another you meant one would call the other

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER can be any 16bytes of data.  Per:

> a string constant in the form xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx,
>   in which each x is a hexadecimal digit in the range 0-9 or a-f. For
>   example, 6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF is a valid
>   uniqueidentifier value.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

So any 16 character or less varchar can be round-tripped through a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER.  Eg

```
declare @d varchar(16) = 'hello world'

declare @u uniqueidentifier = cast(cast(@d as varbinary(16)) as uniqueidentifier)

select cast(cast(@u as varbinary(16)) as varchar(16))
```

Comment: Thank you David for this suggestion. I'll definitely keep this in mind for future.

Answer (score 1):

To add some general thoughts:

As you were told already, a GUID has a length of 16 bytes.

Assuming you can reduce your string to plain latin lower-case characters you have to deal with 26, together with numbers with 36 different values (not speaking of any dot, comma or question mark etc).

The count of bits reflects the number of possible values. One byte of 8 bit can represent 256 (2^8) different values. For 26 letters you'd need at least 5 bit (2^5=32), together with the numbers you'd have to go up to 6 bit (64 values). The 16-byte GUID represents 128 bits (16x8=128). You could divide this by 5 (~25) or by 6 (~21).

That means: Reduced to 26 plain latin characters you could (with quite some effort) encode up to 25 characters in the memory allocated by one GUID (by using chunks of 5 bits). Together with numbers you are limited to a length of 21.

If you want to deal with any `VARCHAR` value (which is extended ASCII), you can  translate a string to binary and then to GUID and back easily (David Brown showed this in his answer), as long as you limit this to a length of 16 characters.

Otherwise you would need some kind of dictionary on both sides...